# How do I change the color of a UITextfield Placeholder in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swift4.1

How do I change the color of a UITextfield Placeholder in Swift 4? Seems like a simple task but I am having some trouble figuring it out as I am new programming and Swift. I want to change the color programmatically.

```
        tf.placeholder = "Name"
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: UIFont.Weight.thin)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
someTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Placeholder text", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red])
```

Comment: Your code cannot be added to mine